# The links in my navigation bar are not showing as "current" when they are active

Tags: html, css

I have different background color for the active/current links in the horizontal navigation bar. When a link is clicked and that particular page is open, it is supposed to show the different color (as in the 'home page' link) but it is not happening.

Please help. I hope I have described myself clearly. The site is: http://www.successrealization.com

Example of what I want:-
At one of my another site http://healthsewa.org/my-site/portfolio.html , it is happening properly, the way I want it. I have no idea how. The code is almost the same.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you're setting the `class="current"` correctly for the other links

Comment: The pop-up that appears whenever navigating away from Home tab might not be necessary. It doesn't appear for any of the other tabs. Your site is working reasonably well, so that's why I mentioned that that pop-up apology window might be unnecessary and cause more annoyance than it is worth. Just a suggestion, not a complaint, okay?

Comment: Similar but not duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382664/css-how-to-change-colour-of-active-navigation-page-menu The accepted answer might be helpful to your specific inquiry.

Comment: Thank you very much, Feral Oink. I will remove it now. Actually, when I put that up, my site was under construction. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Do I have to set class="current" for all the links? Cause when I set class="current" for other links also, they show me green color even when I am not on that page. Like home page link is always current. But I don't want such for every link.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a way for the page to detect which "tab" it is on. That won't magically happen actually. You'll need to save the clicked tab somehow so that after postback the selected tab and be set as current or active.

You can do this by using localStorage if you are only worried about a modern browser. You can also do this with a cookie as well.

Here is an example of setting a variable with localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('tab', 'set ur tab index etc here');
```

You would do the above when the tab is clicked. on the page load you would conversely get the tab index.

```
localStorage.getItem('tab');
```

Using jQuery or js set the tab active based on this index that you set/get.

EDIT: setup a jsfiddle and I'll complete out the example if you wish.

Comment: Hey! In this example page - [link](http://healthsewa.org/my-site/portfolio.html) It is doing without any cookies or local storage setting. And I have no idea how it is happening there. It is almost the same code.

Comment: I can't investigate at the moment but usually it is one of the following cookie, localStorage, session variable, single page site. In a single page site its not posting back so you could store it in a plain ol' js var.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the class current for home and add class current for the tab you click. like when you click on **About** ---> add the class current to that anchor tag and **Home** ---> remove the class current from anchor tag.

You can use the addClass and removeClass methods to add and remove class dynamically.