# How to change color of active navigation page menu

Tags: html, css

So I found the thread [CSS: How to change colour of active navigation page menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382664/css-how-to-change-colour-of-active-navigation-page-menu) and was trying to do it but had no success.

Here is my menu:

```
<div id="navMain">
     <ul>

    <li id="current"><a href="user.php" >User</a></li>
    <li><a href="../admin/admin.php">Create User</a></li>   
    <li><a href="../admin_reg/admin_reg.php">Create Admin</a></li>  

    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
/***************************/
/* Genral Navigation Rules */
/***************************/
#navMain {
    text-align: center;
    margin:-70px ;
}   
#navMain ul {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}

#navMain ul li {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}

#navMain ul li a {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    color:  #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#navMain ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: #EF7D50;
}
#current {
    color: #EF7D50;
}
#current a{
    color: #EF7D50;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wp2R6/) for what I currently have.

Comment: "_had no success_" Will you clarify your goal? What do you expect to happen, what is currently happening, and what problems have you encountered that prevent you from accomplishing it?

Comment: The code you posted seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jTkvu/.

Comment: do you want to adda class active?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
#navMain #current a{
    color: #EF7D50;
}
```

The problem is that your `#navMain ul li a` rule is more specific than the `#current a` so it has precedence..

Using two ids for the above rule `#navMain #current a` makes it be more specific and so it gets applied..