# jQuery or PHP to remember pressed menu item

Tags: php, jquery, menu, highlight

I want to know what is the easiest way to make a menu remember which item is currently active. For example if I press "Services" in the menu and it loads the services page, I want the "Services" item in the menu to be highlighted. What should I use jquery or php, How?

Thank you for any suggestions..

Comment: Polling and/or opinion based questions are not allowed here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382664/css-how-to-change-colour-of-active-navigation-page-menu

Comment: Is not a POLL, is a question, I have no idea how to do it, I need advice on how to proceed ok?

Comment: did you try using css Pseudo-class :active?

Comment: Are you're menu items named the same as your page names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based purely on the URL. If your pages have the same names as your menu items, you could simply parse out the URL to find the appropriate item to apply a class or style to. Please, not though that this solution is contingent on the fact that your pages are named the same as your menu items.

For example:

```
// With a URL like:
// http://www.thisisanexample.com/modules/pro/blogs/blogs.php?action=my_page&mode=main

var url = window.location.href;
url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('.'));

// Sample switch to add class to appropriate menu item
switch (url) {
    case " --> some page <-- ":
        // add menu item for this page
        break;
    case "blogs":
        $('#blog-menuItem').addClass('active');
        break;
    case " --> some other page <-- ":
        // add menu item for this page
        break;
}

// url would effectively contain "blogs" after the parsing.
```

This code is lightweight and prevents you from having to keep up with any server side variables or cookies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, maybe with a little tweak to make this automate it will work..

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by automated though. You could wrap it in a document ready `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` or shorthand `$(function () { });` so that it automatically ran when the DOM is ready. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy in PHP. You could write a quick function for simple pages... example:

```
<?php
function page() { return basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"); }
?>

<a href="foobar.php" class="<?php if(page() == "foobar") echo "active"; ?>">Foo</a>
<a href="bazbiz.php" class="<?php if(page() == "bazbiz") echo "active"; ?>">Baz</a>
```

With that said, this is a rough example. It really depends on your application, goals, framework, etc. Nothing is ever cut and dry without knowing what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that some of the links look bad like "modules/pro/blogs/blogs.php?action=my_page&mode=main" and some look like "browse.php".. I was thinking using jquery cookie plugin..

Comment: You could always be cheap and bind an event handler on an A click with jquery, then set cookies (omnomnom)... on page load, scan for cookies and apply "active" classes as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you load a page, you create the menu from scratch, which means you can modify it however you want to.

Generally, if you load a different page, you could use PHP this way :

```
<a href="myLink.php" class="<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/mypage") echo "myClass"; ?>">Foo</a>
```

You can also use CSS to style the link that is currently being visited with the active pseudo-class.

```
a:active
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

If you need your menus to look different without changing the current page, then you can use Javascript.

Here is an example of adding a class to a menu you clicked with Jquery :

```
$("#menuId").click(function()
{
  $("#menuId").addClass("myClass");
});
```

There are many other possible ways to do this, you could go as far as using cookies or even sessions to do this, but I think in your situation the PHP or CSS version would work best.

Answer (score 0):

I would use local storage (works in all browsers and ie 8+).

set like this:

```
localStorage.activeItem = 'services';
```

and get like this:

```
$('#output').html('active item: ' + localStorage.activeItem);
```

edit:
a quick note - localStorage is saved on the users computer, so it will remain even if the user leaves your site and returns again months later.  With that in mind, you may want to clear your activeItem before they leave or before the first page load.