# manipulating list bullets in jsp

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

On my website I have a single JSP page that I use to list all links to examples which looks like the following.

example_links.jsp:

```
 <div class="example_links" style="float:left; width:48%">
 Basic:
   <ul>
     <li><a href="basicssp.jsp">Basic initialisation</a> - Server Side Processing</li>
     <li><a href="basiccrud.jsp">Basic initialisation</a> - basic CRUD example</li>
     <li><a href="validation.jsp">Field Validation</a> - includes Theme for DataTables</li>
     <li><a href="multi_filter.jsp">Multiple Filter Searches</a> - perform search on specific columns</li>
     <li><a href="customdates.jsp">Custom Date Fields</a></li>
     <li><a href="exporttoexcel.jsp">Export To Excel</a></li>
   </ul>
   <br>General Purpose Database Access - Examples without DataTables:
   <ul>
     <li><a href="basicconnection.jsp">Basic Connection</a> - demonstrates how to perform a basic database connection.</li>
     <li><a href="fielddata.jsp">Populating Text Fields From JSON String</a> - demonstrates a Profiles page for the user allowing them to update their personal data.</li>
     <li><a href="selectdata.jsp">Populating A Select Listbox</a></li>
     <li><a href="exporttoexcel2.jsp">Export To Excel Without DataTables</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="example_links" style="float:right; width:48%">
 Advanced:
 <ul>
     <li><a href="join1.jsp">Joined Tables 1</a> - joining multiple tables - working with objects</li>
     <li><a href="join2.jsp">Joined Tables 2</a> - working with lookup tables and arrays of objects</li>                    
     <li><a href="self.jsp">Self referencing join tables</a></li>   
     <li><a href="functions.jsp">Using Database Functions And Old Style Joins</a></li>      
     <li><a href="functions2.jsp">Using Database Functions On Where Conditions</a></li>                     
   </ul         
 </div>
```

At the bottom of each example page I use this tag <%@ include file="example_links.jsp" %> to insert the lists.

My CSS styling is:

```
div.example_links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

If I include this additional styling:

```
div.example_links ul li {
  background-image: url(/jed/media/images/purple_square.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 5px; 
  padding-left: 14px;
}
```

it affects all the li elements by prepending a bullet image.

[image]

What I would prefer is to invoke this styling only on the list item that is currently being displayed so that when the user looks at the list, he knows immediately which item he is currently viewing.  All the others would have no bullets at all.

What's the best way to implement this functionality?  Maybe there is some way of telling the example_links.jsp page which page is calling it, so that it knows which li element it should impose the styling on?  Please advise.

Comment: can 't you use the css `a:active selector` in such a case ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a:active.  How does that work?  Can you show me an example?

Comment: don't bother. It thought it could be used for the currently active link, but it was mistaken. Sorry.

Comment: You might find this answer useful tough : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382664/css-how-to-change-colour-of-active-navigation-page-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use CSS 's psuedo-selectors. Just to give you a pointer, consider your HTML as such:

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Basic initialisation</a> <span>- Server Side Processing</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Basic initialisation</a><span> - basic CRUD example</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Field Validation</a><span> - includes Theme for DataTables</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Multiple Filter Searches</a><span> - perform search on specific columns</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Custom Date Fields</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Export To Excel</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

provide CSS as such:

```
ul {
list-style-type:square;
color:#FF3E96;
 }

ul li > span {
    color:Black;;
}

ul > li:hover {
    background-color:#FFDEAD;
}

.selected {
    background-color:#CFCFCF;
}
```

This should give you the effect you are looking for.

You can see this here-> http://jsfiddle.net/stFDH/1/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Well...that helps somewhat, but the list items not selected in your example still have a bullet next to them.

Comment: OK.. I've been playing with this and have managed to isolate a given list item with a bullet.  So now that we have the css portion figured out, the next issue is a purely java one in that in the example_links.jsp page how do I determine which list item requires the class="selected" attribute?