# Creating a smart button menu in Drupal with in block div and css style

Tags: php, html, css, button, drupal

Hi I've been trying to create a smart button menu set in an drupal block that remembers which button has been clicked (which site it is on). For reasons that don't matter, it is not a menu it's an in-block item. I created the following in-line:

```
<div><a href="site1" class="button" style="width: 110px;">Overview</a></div>
<div><a href="site2" class="button" style="width: 120px;">Instruments</a></div>
<div><a href="site3" class="button" style="width: 110px;">Travel</a></div>
```

This coupled with the following css produces lovely buttons:

```
.button {
background-color: #61210b;
color: white;
float:left;
padding: 2px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
border-radius: 5px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'verdana';
margin-bottom: 10px;}

.button:hover {
background-color: green;
color: white;}

.button:focus {
background-color: green;
color: white;}

.button:active {
background-color: green;
color: white;}
```

So everything above works great. However, the green activation color does NOT stay. As soon as I go click it goes back to what it was before. I want it to 'show' the page it is on with it's color change and only the currently chosen button will have the green color. What I have not works great except for that little issue. I've read around on the site a bit and here are some things that do not work:
--> inline php, creates errors link unreadable, if I define a class as selected with a different color, this does NOT work:

```
<a href="site1" class="<?php if(page() == "foobar") echo "selected"; else echo "button" ?>">Overview</a>
```

What also does not work is defining an additional class in the `<a href >` or `<div>` to make it 'selected', at best if I use the css file and do

.selected a { color: green; } 
   #selected a { color: green: }

I can permanently change the color to green, which is not what I want at all. I saw the discussion previously of using lists `<li id="selected">` to create menues but not only does this not give me very nice buttons like my div format does, it also flat out does not work. See: [CSS: How to change colour of active navigation page menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382664/css-how-to-change-colour-of-active-navigation-page-menu?lq=1)

The color just changes permanently, I only want it to change color if page=page of link. Since I'm using div this means I also cannot use the other pseudo-class-selector tricks like :target or :root. I have a feeling php is the way to go but I don't know why it can't be read in-line from my drupal box item. It has no problems with html or css in-line. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a custom menu? I am not much familiar with drupal's code, it should output a class for the "current" page in menu - have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/251914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I heard back from our system administrator and Drupal safety settings do not allow for in-line php or java scripting. There is literally no way to do this with div statements. The only way is to delete everything and make a new block of type menu block. In a menu block the psuedo-class :active will stay active if you use css

```
li .active
```

otherwise you can try to get php enabled but most drupal areas do not allow that or java scripting (at least it's not allowed where I am).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

CSS

```
.button:active, .button.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

PHP

```
<a href="site1" class="<?php if(page() == "foobar") echo "selected button"; else echo "button"; ?>">Overview</a>
```

what you wrote is calling for something else...
`.selected a` is targeting any element with the class "selected" which is inside an anchor tag, what you mean is an anchor tag which has the class selected = `a.selected`

Comment: Maybe a bit of clarification is in order, I've never gotten php to work before, I though I could just do a quick in-line alteration but the "<?" element seems to cause a error, it won't read the class at all with the php in it. This must be a drupal issue. If I use any php:"<?php ...?>" I just get the echo statements printing on the page, it doesn't even close the <a href>.

Comment: there's a missing semi-colon after "button".. should be "button"; BTW this is your code I'd assume you know what it does? PHP is checking if the current page is "foobar" and if that is true it will add the classes "selected button" otherwise it will be just the "button" class, I'm assuming there is a conditional statement for each link in your menu, right?